# Next JS SEO content not being picked up by search engines

Tags: next.js, seo

I'm using Next v10.2.0. When I check my devtools, I can see my page title, descriptions etc in my code, but search engines seem not to be picking them up. I have Google Tag Manager, MailChimp and some other 3rd party scripts running on my website. Could they be making the content in my  section invisible to the search engines. Please help out if you've experienced anything like this, or have a solution.

My _document.js file:

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang='en'>
        <Head>
          {/* Google Tag Manager Script */}
          <script
            defer
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
        new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
        'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
        })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GTM_KEY}');`,
            }}
          ></script> 

          <meta name="facebook-domain-verification" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" /> 
          <meta httpEquiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
          <meta name='theme-color' content={theme.palette.primary.main} />
          <link
            rel='stylesheet'
            href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap'
          />

          <script
            defer
            type='text/javascript'
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: process.env.rawJsFromFile }}
          ></script> 
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
          <noscript
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `<iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GTM_KEY}"
              height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>`,
            }}
          ></noscript>
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

MyDocument.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets()
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage

  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: App => props => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
    })

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    styles: [
      ...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles),
      sheets.getStyleElement(),
    ],
  }
}
```

My Homepage:

```
import React from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>
            Page title here
        </title>
        <meta
          name='description'
          content='page description here'
        />
        <link rel='icon' href='/favicon.ico' />
      </Head>

      <div>
          Page Content
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Are you rendering anything Server side? Can the URL be shared here to take a look

Comment: Sadly, I can't share the URL but isn't server side rendering supposed to improve SEO performance?

Comment: The content I need like the page titles and descriptions are all there, but I'm wondering if it's possible that a script loading in the <head> can make search engines unable to read the other contents in the <head>

Comment: Where are you setting the page title and description? That's not present in the code you shared. Please provide all the relevant code.

Comment: I have added the code for my homepage. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this should be a problem, try disabling javascript on your browser and make sure you are still seing the title and meta tags. also consider using google search console to debug SEO related isssues

Comment: When I disable JavaScript on my browser, I don't see any of the meta tags in the <Head/> of my pages, but the meta tags I put in _document.js or _app.js show up.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `next/head` like this:

```
import Head from 'next/head'

function HeadPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>HTML Title of page</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
        <meta name="facebook-domain-verification" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" /> 
      </Head>
      <p>Hello website visitors!</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```

Comment: That's how I use it on all the pages already. I only import from next/document in my _document.js file